# How to do php jquery load_more data

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am coding php jquery load more button, when i click the load_more button work successfully and when i click 2 nd time did not working my button, please help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZLfh.jpg

i tried to when i click load_more button, then load the data in database, but this code is first time running correctly and 2nd time load_more button not working correctly, i will up`enter code here`load my code 2 images in this post, please see my code and help me

index page

```
<body>
    <div id="as">
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM product limit 2";
        $result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
        $last_id;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        ?>
            <h3 ><?php echo $row['product_name']?></h3>

        <?php
            $last_id = $row['id'];
        }
    ?>
        <input type="button" id="btn" data-id="<?php echo $last_id ?>" value="Load More ..." />
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                var a = $(this).data('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'load.php',
                        data : {last_id:a},
                        success:function(data) {
                            $('#btn').remove();
                            $('#as').append(data);
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

load_more.php

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id > {$_GET['last_id']} ORDER BY id asc limit 2";
$result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
if($result) {
    $last_id;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<h3>{$row['product_name']}</h3>";
        $last_id = $row['id'];
    }
    ?>

    <button type="button" id="btn" data-id="<?php echo $last_id ?>">Load More ...</button>

    <?php
}
```

?>

`i expect output is when i click the load_more button load 2 data in my page`

Comment: why you are removing the button on ajax success result?

Comment: if i did not remove my button, there have a two buttons, becouse load_more.php page have a another button

Comment: I bet, due to the removal of first button your button listener get detached. And then you are adding new button dynamically but not binding the button with listener that in turn when you click on the button it would be performing nothing. You should rather output the "last_id" in ajax success and then only update the data-id of your button. Neither remove the button nor add the same button dynamically. It will make your event listeners useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please Follow this blog post](https://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database/)

[Or this one](https://makitweb.com/load-more-results-with-jqueryajax-and-php/)

[Or this one](http://tutorialsmint.com/tutorial/load-more-data-while-scrolling-page-down-with-jquery-ajax-and-php-1546945742)

Happy Coding...